# Isolating js files that are needed for one test suite

Tags: javascript, requirejs, mocha.js, karma-runner, google-chrome-headless

I am using karma/mocha/chrome headless for my test stack.

```
--js 1
document.addEventListener('test', ...);
do sth more.

--js 2
 document.addEventListener('test', ...);    
 do sth more differently.

-- test suite 1
   require(test1)
   i am dispatching the test event here to test js 1

-- test suite 2
   require(test2)
   I am dispatchinh the test event here to test js 2
```

The problem is that both of these files will be now available globally. When I am running the test suite 2, both js1 and js2 events are going to listen my dispatch because js1 will be still globally available.

My perfect scenario would be. Load js1 to test suite 1 and encapsulate it there. Hacky way would be remove it after the tests are ran.

My question is, how to make sure that needed js files are loaded locally in the scope of one test suite? Basically load only nesseccary files for the specific test suite and keep them isolated from rest of test suites.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to scope your modules to the relevant test file?

If that's the case then you can load your modules like so:

```
const sharedModule = require('some/shared/module');

describe('some test', function() {
    const scopedModule = require('some/path/to/module');

    it('should...', function() {
        // Test code...
    })

)
```

This would result in your module being loaded only when the test begins to execute, being scoped inside that block.